# JSF 2 <f:selectItems> not recognizing itemLabel and itemValue attributes

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, facelets, el

I have the following dropdown in a Facelets page:

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{contactBean.selectedContact}" converter="#{contactConverter}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{contactsHolder.contacts}" var="contact"
    itemLabel="#{contact.firstName}" itemValue="#{contact}" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

The problem is, no matter what I put in for `itemLabel` (JSF EL expression or just plain text), it doesn't display. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Here's `ContactConverter`:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "contactConverter")
@RequestScoped
public class ContactConverter implements Converter, Serializable {
    @ManagedProperty(value = "#{contactsHolder}")
    private ContactsHolder contactsHolder;

    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value) {
        return contactsHolder.getContacts().get(value);
    }

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) {
        return ((Contact) value).getContactID();
    }
    //getter & setters...
}
```

And `ContactsHolder`:

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class ContactsHolder implements Serializable {
    private Map<String, Contact> contacts;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        contacts = new LinkedHashMap<String, Contact>();
        //get Contacts data and populate map...
    }
    //getters & setters...
}
```

Comment: Using plain text should however work.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You're feeding a `Map<String, Contact>` to `<f:selectItems value>`. Each item in `var` attribute will be a [`Map.Entry<String, Contact>`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html) which has only `getKey()` and `getValue()` methods returning the `String` map key and `Contact` map value respectively. The `Map.Entry` class indeed doesn't have a `getFirstName()` method.

Fix it accordingly:

```
<f:selectItems value="#{contactsHolder.contacts}" var="contact"
    itemLabel="#{contact.value.firstName}" itemValue="#{contact.value}" />
```

Or, if you target a Servlet 3.0 / EL 2.2 capable container which allows invoking non-getter methods, so that you can use [`Map#values()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#values%28%29) to get a `Collection<Contact>`:

```
<f:selectItems value="#{contactsHolder.contacts.values()}" var="contact"
    itemLabel="#{contact.firstName}" itemValue="#{contact}" />
```

Or, make the `#{contactsHolder.contacts}` a `List<Contact>` instead so that your initial view code will work:

```
<f:selectItems value="#{contactsHolder.contacts}" var="contact"
    itemLabel="#{contact.firstName}" itemValue="#{contact}" />
```

Comment: As always, BalusC, your quick and detailed answer is greatly appreciated!